# What would be the better way?

Tags: c, pointers

This is what I believe would be the better way.

```
int main()
{

    node *head;
    insertAfter(&head, 14, 12);
}

void insertAfter(node **head, int item, int after)
{

    node *ptr, *loc;

    loc = searchUnsorted(*head, after); //copy of *head passed 

    if(loc == (node *) NULL)
            return;
    ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    ptr -> info = item;
    ptr -> next = loc -> next;
    loc -> next = ptr;
}
```

And this is what my teacher thinks would be it.

```
int main()
{

    node *head;
    insertAfter(head, 14, 12);
}
void insertAfter(node *head, int item, int after)
{

    node *ptr, *loc;

    loc = searchUnsorted(head, after); //copy of *head passed 

    if(loc == (node *) NULL)
            return;
    ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    ptr -> info = item;
    ptr -> next = loc -> next;
    loc -> next = ptr;
}
```

Comment: Neither of you actually sets `head` which makes me call B.S. that one of those is from your teacher. Anyway. Not clear what you are a) trying to do and b) what the question is.

Comment: The only change you made is passing a pointer to a pointer instead of just a pointer? Or am I missing something? Can you elaborate why do you think your version is better? For me there isn't any performance boost and the code is sligly less readable.

Comment: @Caribou you didn't miss anything. I just thought it would be better if I just passed the address, instead of a copy. That's how it works, doesn't it?

Comment: @ShubhamGirdhar Your teacher does exactly that. He declares node pointer called head. This node pointer holds only the adress to an actual variable, not a value itself. Thus, when you pass a pointer to a function you pass a copy of a pointer, not a copy of an object itself. Your version goes one step further, and passes an adress to that pointer (i. e. a pointer to a pointer to a variable)

Comment: @ShubhamGirdhar `node head` would pass a copy. `node *head` passes a pointer. `node **head` passes a pointer to a pointer (a double pointer). Basically, `type *` is a pointer to `type`. Double pointers have their uses, this isn't one of them. The comment "//copy of \*head passed" is incorrect, or very misleading, it's passing a pointer; this is why comments explaining what can be read from the code are typically avoided, comments explain *why* not the *what*.

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should never have spaces around them.

Comment: @Caribou In mine, I passed the address of the pointer to the function and then dereferenced it and then passed the dereferenced pointer to function searchUnsorted(). I believe that made 2 copies in total of the pointer. Also, in my teacher's, 3 copies were made. Could you look into it again, and explain if what I explained matches what I wrote?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the first code is more nearly correct than the second, but neither is correct.  The second code might be OK if the function was changed to `node *insertAfter(node *head, int item, int after)` and it was called like `head = insertAfter(head, item, after);` — then it could work.  You'd return the value in `head` unless you created it.  Note that you'd need to initialize `node *head = NULL;` in `main()` — in both versions of the code.

Comment: @ShubhamGirdhar Your code and your teachers code make exactly same number of copies. The difference is level of indirection. Your code doesn't imply need for this indirection. You would use a pointer to a pointer if you would like to change the passed object. //EDIT Stephan Lechner explained that very well :)

Comment: passing in `node **head` strongly suggests that you intend to update the callers `node * head`. Which in fact you are not. So teacher is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question should be "when should I pass a pointer (i.e. your teacher's version), and when should I pass a pointer to a pointer (i.e. your version)".

In the context of linked list, passing a pointer to a pointer makes sense if the function may exchange the head of the list. Consider, for example, a function called `insertAtFront(node**head, int item)`, which will insert a value *before* the current head and therefore the caller has to be informed about the "new" head.

```
insertAtFront(node**head, int item) {
  node *prevHead = *head; 
  *head = createNode(item);  // assign *head a new value; caller's pointer value will change
  *head->next = prevHead;
}
insertAtFrontWrong(node*head, int item) {
  node *prevHead = head; 
  head = createNode(item);  // only local variable head will get new value; caller's value will not change
  head->next = prevHead;
}

int main() {
  node *main_head = createNode(10);
  insertAtFront(& main_head,20); // OK; afterwards main_head will point to the new head
  insertAtFrontWrong(main_head,30); // Not OK; value of main_head will remain as is
}
```

However, if a function will by definition not exchange the head, it is not necessary to pass a pointer to a pointer; a "plain" pointer is sufficient:

```
void insertAfterSuperflousIndirection(node **head, int item, int after) {
   // use (*head)->... to traverse/change successors
   // *head will, however, never be set to a new value, so indirection is superfluous
}

void insertAfter(node *head, int item, int after) {
   // use head->... to traverse/change successors
}
```

So in your case, if "insertAfter" will never exchange the head, I'd prefer the teacher's version.

Answer (score 0):

You're teacher is trying to pass by value and you're trying to pass by reference. In my opinion your approach is better than teacher's. But it does vary from what you want to do with.
If you want your head pointer to be updated during the callee function  then pass by reference is good. By this any changes done on head pointer memory location by the callee is updated also in the main.

Suppose head -> 0xabc123 ( Memory address of head) and content 0xadf432

Your teacher's theory

head of insertAfter() stores content of head(of main) ie 0xadf432 . You can play around with the nodes, But you cannot modify the content of head(of main) ie cant change the value of 0xabc123 to something else.

But in your approach you could do this. Thus able to change the head(of main) content ( problem after your function operations) your head may point to new node.........